How can I store boolean array of size 3000 efficiently in milvus?
I have a boolean array which represents store-availability of retail products across 3000 different stores.
so, my schema looks like below:
product_id = FieldSchema(
    name="product_id", 
    dtype=DataType.INT64, 
    is_primary=True,
    auto_id=False
)

product_title_vector = FieldSchema(
    name="product_title_vector", 
    dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR,
    dim=768,
)

store_availability = FieldSchema(
    name="store_availability", 
    dtype=DataType.ARRAY, 
    element_type=DataType.BOOL,
    max_capacity=3000
)


The catch here is as per the general rule, boolean array of size 3000 will take ~3KB per record.
I have 5 million items/records. so in total store_availability field alone will take 15GB as per the below calculation.
memory = 3000 bytes/item * 5,000,000 items = 15GB

And then I perform a milvus search with expr for filtering results based on given store-id like below:
query_vector = np.random.random((1, 128)).astype(np.float32)
query_vector_resized = np.resize(query_vector, (1, 768))

store_id = 1

filter_expr = "store_availability[{}] == true".format(store_id - 1)
print("Filter Expression : ", filter_expr)

search_params = {"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 16}}
search_results = collection.search(
    data=query_vector_resized,
    anns_field="product_title_vector",
    expr=filter_expr,
    param=search_params,
    limit=1
    
)

I am finding this 15GB for a single metadata field as resource-intensive. Although it is better performant, what if the number of stores increase to 40,000 in future.
I tried sparse-vector representation but most of the products are available on 80% of the stores and still it consumes a lot of space.
Any approaches that can be suggested for making this space-efficient while having filter-expr within search will be of great help!

For 3,000 stores, you should be able to store that information in 325 bytes. No idea how that can be represented in your database and implemented in your filtering though. Maybe bitwise operations?

ok, when you say 325 bytes, I assume it is through bitwise. Please correct me if I  misunderstood.
